# Android Rotation Issue

Tags: android

I have an application that is not calling onConfigurationChanged, but only in one specific case. I have 2 activities, A and B. Activity A has a gridview, and I change the number of columns based on orientation. This works fine using onConfigurationChanged.

However, if I follow these steps, I don't get an onConfigurationChanged():

1. Activity A, Orientation1 -> Activity B (Still Orientation1)
2. Rotate the device while in Activity B (now Orientation2)
3. Back to Activity A, now in Orientation2. onResume is fired, and I adjust the layout.
4. While in Activity A, rotate back to Orientation1. Nothing is fired (onCreate, onResume, onConfigurationChanged... etc.) Layout is now wrong (with number of columns set to Orientation2).

After this, if I keep rotating while in Activity A, the rest of the rotations fire onConfigurationChanged and the layout adjusts accordingly. It's only that first rotation after coming back from another activity. It doesn't matter which orientation I start in, the result is the same.

Is there something besides onConfigurationChanged I should be looking at?

Comment: Please post your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: create folder name it as layout-land and copy paste all your layouts from the layout folder , and paste them in layout-land and do the changes on them. as they will be landscape automatically just edit some heights and widths.

Answer (score 1):

onConfigurationChanged will only fire in the active context (visible Activity, or Fragments).

Instead of changing the number of columns in onConfigurationChanged, use a different layout in the `res/layout` and `res/layout-land` folders.
In XML define the column count. This way you don't even need to override onConfigurationChanged and Android will take care of the dirty work for you :D

The `layout-land` layout wil be used in a landscape orientation and the `layout` layout will be used in portrait (or be used as a default).